# Doctest thinks DocTestParser doesn't exist?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, doctest

I'm trying to use sphinx to create documentation. I'm currently following this tutorial from PyCon 2016 by [Eric Holscher](http://I'm%20trying%20to%20use%20sphinx%20to%20create%20documentation.%20I'm%20currently%20following%20this%20tutorial%20from%20PyCon%202016%20by%20[Eric%20Holscher](https://sphinx-tutorial.readthedocs.io/)). During step two is the first time autodocs is used. I set the file path to find autodocs and after that the documents wouldn't compile. I keep getting `AttributeError: module 'doctest' has no attribute 'DocTestParser'`. I couldn't find much online except for a couple issues on [GitHub](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/5473) that were just installation issues. Any suggestions would help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you're not naming your file/module `doctest.py` because it will conflict.

Comment: nothing else in the project or my directories has the name `doctest.py`

Comment: @JulianCamilleri, the error points to the correct file. I also checked and the file does have the DocTestParser class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the conf.py file I was telling it to use doctest in the sphinx extension folder like so; `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../venv/Lib/site-packages/sphinx/ext/'))`.

The should just point to the Lib folder; `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../venv/Lib/'))`

This complied cleanly.